# Using a custom .otf font in an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-core, fonts, font-face

I have a .otf font file that I am trying to use in my ASP.NET Core project.

In the wwwroot folder, I have created another folder named *font* where the .otf file resides.

In my css file I have the following:

```
@@font-face {
    font-family: 'Nexa Light';
    src: local('../font/Nexa Light.otf'), url('../font/Nexa Light.otf');
}

body {
    font-family: 'Nexa Light';
}
```

The font has not been applied and there are no errors in Chrome Dev console so.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I assume the double `@` is a typo. Also try in other browsers (eg. Firefox has some additional font info in its dev tools).

Comment: Apart from the double `@`, the `..` means that the font file must be relative to the css file.

Comment: And also, you folder name is `fonts`, while the path uses `../font/<font-name.otf>`

Answer (score 4):

> I have created another folder named **fonts** where the .otf file resides

In your code you have written **font** in the path : `src: local('../font/Nexa Light.otf'), url('../font/Nexa Light.otf');`

- Check that font folder name
- Avoid using blank spaces (whitespace) in font names, use instead "_" or "-" to avoid blank spaces (whitespace).

These can be cause above issue.

Try using below code :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(fontname.woff);
}
```